# Directed Acyclic Word Graph Constuction

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

Assuming i have 3 words in my DAWG: do, dot, bot i will have this:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/dawgp.png/

This graph tells that 'bo' is also a word. Which indeed not. Node 'o' is EOW if only path comes from 'd', not 'b'

I obviously miss smth but i do now know what.

Comment: But you don't have 3 words in your graph, you have 4 letters.  I think that what you are missing is that your data structure is simply inadequate as a representation of a word recogniser.  Which takes me to the real question -- what are you trying to do ?  What computation do you expect that graph to support ?

Comment: I am trying to hold a dictionary in DAWG structure. Directed acyclic word graph. In my graph, 'b' and 'd' letters are root nodes, and words are marked with EOW (end-of-word). So if you start from root nodes until EOW nodes you get, b->o->t and d->o->t, d->o which are OK, and also B->O which is not intended

Comment: Then, I repeat, your data structure is not adequate for the task you are attempting.  Your DAWG has no 'memory', it doesn't record anything about previous transitions so when it gets to 'o' it doesn't 'know' whether it came from 'd' or 'b' so can't support the operation of determining whether or not you have found a complete word. I don't think that you can fix this, you have to choose another data structure for your dictionary.

Comment: OK, i understand what you mean. I thought DAWG is sufficient for what i am trying to accomplish, but i fail to implement it correctly. As this link, [c# dawg](http://www.dotnetperls.com/directed-acyclic-word-graph) describes DAWG implementation that is used to recognize words. Then this implementation is also inadequate opposed to what it claims. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I understand a bit better what you are trying to do and how a DAG fits into your work.  If you want a graph to represent the dictionary containing the words 'do', 'dot' and 'bot' you would have the edges;

```
.->d->o'->t'
.->b->o->t'
```

where '.' represents the root of your graph and the branches are entirely separate, that is the edge 'd->o' points to a different occurrence of 'o' from the one referred to in 'b->o'.  By trying to have both edges point to the same occurrence of 'o' you've malformed the graph.

Note that in my 'graph' I've used a ' symbol to indicate that a letter can be the end of a word by reading from the root to that symbol. If I have time later I'll do a better picture of the graph.

Comment: OK, I think I figured out what I am missing while trying to reply you. Your graph is actually an initial graph (A Trie). Then what I understood from the link above, i needed to merge identical sub-tries and i merged o->t sub-tries. But actually they are not identical because one of them is o->t' and other is o'->t'. So, indeed EOW is also a branch and causes subtrees to be different. Final tree structure of my word set should be like this: [DAWG](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/1599/dawgc.png). Thank you HP Mark!